# SQL calculate number of days in month excluding weekends and holidays days

Tags: sql, vertica

I have approximately the same table (excluding count column). I want to calculate the number of working days (Mon-Fri) and exclude public holidays.

[image]

I tried to try the following query

```
SELECT count(distinct(date)) from MYDB where dummy <> 1
```

However, it gives the only total number of days including weekends. Additionally, if use this command it counts distinct dates, however, my dates do not show a full month, so another logic should've used. Could you help to figure out which code is better to use?

Answer (score 1):

there should be a function in Vertica that extracts weekday from date, so to exclude weekends you'll need to add another condition like

```
extract(dow from date) not in (6,0)
```

(6 is Sat, 0 is Sun in this case)

Comment: The column Counts is now showing the number of workday (1-5) of the week.

Comment: not sure what did you do and what are you trying to achieve... I mean add a second condition: `where dummy <> 1 and extract(dow from date) not in (6,0)`